# Detect MouseEvent on empty JLabel

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

i'm trying to detect MouseEvent on JLabel.
I have an array of JLabel (`candidateLabel = new JLabel [9]`). Some of his JLabel contain a number, some do not. I already implement an option to add text if I left clicks and it is not empty. I would now like to be able to detect right clicks on my empty label, but that does not seem to happen.

Here is the code :

```
package sudoku.view;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class CaseComponent extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String CANDIDATES = "candidate";
    private static final String DIGIT = "digit";
    private static final int CASE_DIM = 60;
    private static final int DIGIT_SIZE = 38;
    private MouseAdapter candidatesMouseAdapter;
    private MouseAdapter digitMouseAdapter;
    private GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraint;
    private Color caseColor;
    private Color initialCaseColor;
    private JLabel[] candidatesLabel;
    private JLabel digitLabel;
    private String currentState;
    private boolean modifiable;

    public CaseComponent(Color caseColor, String currentState) {
        super();
        this.initialCaseColor = caseColor;
        this.caseColor = caseColor;
        this.currentState = currentState;
        this.modifiable = true;
        setConfiguration();
        createView();
        placeComponents();
        createController();
    }

    // REQUETES


    public JLabel getDigitLabel() {
        return digitLabel;
    }

    public JLabel[] getCandidatesLabel() {
        return candidatesLabel; 
    }

    public Color getInitialCaseColor() {
        return initialCaseColor;
    }

    public static String getCandidateState() {
        return CANDIDATES;
    }

    public static String getDigitState() {
        return DIGIT;
    }

    public String getCurrentState() {
        return currentState;
    }

    public String getDigitText() {
        return digitLabel.getText();
    }

    public boolean isModifiable() {
        return modifiable;
    }


    // COMMANDES

    public void setModifiable(boolean modifiable) {
        this.modifiable = modifiable;
    }

    public void setCandidatesLabel(Set<Integer> candidates) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            candidatesLabel[i].setText("");
        }
        for (Integer i : candidates) {
            candidatesLabel[i - 1].setText(i + "");
        }
    }

    public void changeLabelForeground(Color color) {
        digitLabel.setForeground(color);

        for (int i = 0; i < candidatesLabel.length; ++i) {
            candidatesLabel[i].setForeground(color);
        }
    }

    public void changeDisplay() {
        if (currentState.equals(CANDIDATES)) {
            candidateDisplay();
        } else {
            digitDisplay();
        }
    }

    public void digitDisplay() {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) getLayout();
        cl.show(this, DIGIT);
        currentState = DIGIT;
    }

    public void candidateDisplay() {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) getLayout();
        cl.show(this, CANDIDATES);
        currentState = CANDIDATES;
    }

    public void addMouseListener() {
        digitLabel.addMouseListener(digitMouseAdapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            candidatesLabel[i].addMouseListener(candidatesMouseAdapter);
        }
    }

    public void removeMouseListener() {
        digitLabel.removeMouseListener(digitMouseAdapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            candidatesLabel[i].removeMouseListener(candidatesMouseAdapter);
        }
    }

    // OUTILS

    private void setConfiguration() {
        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CASE_DIM, CASE_DIM));
        setBackground(caseColor);
    }

    private void createView() {
        gridBagConstraint = new GridBagConstraints();
        candidatesLabel = new JLabel[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            candidatesLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
            candidatesLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        }

        digitLabel = new JLabel();
        digitLabel.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, DIGIT_SIZE));
    }

    private void placeComponents() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            JPanel q = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); {
                q.add(candidatesLabel[i], gridBagConstraint);
            }
            q.setOpaque(false);
            p.add(q);  
        }
        p.setOpaque(false);
        add(p, CANDIDATES);

        p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); {
            p.add(digitLabel, gridBagConstraint);
        }
        p.setOpaque(false);
        add(p, DIGIT);
    }

    private void createController() {
        digitMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) 
                        && isModifiable()) {
                    candidateDisplay();
                }
            }
        };
        digitLabel.addMouseListener(digitMouseAdapter);


        candidatesMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel source = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                    System.out.print(source.getText().equals(""));
                    if (source.getText().equals("")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < candidatesLabel.length; ++i) {
                            if (candidatesLabel[i].equals(source)) {
                                candidatesLabel[i].setText("" + (i - 1));
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        digitDisplay();
                        digitLabel.setText(source.getText());
                    }
                } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatesLabel.length; ++i) {
                        if (candidatesLabel[i].equals(source)) {
                            candidatesLabel[i].setText("");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            candidatesLabel[i].addMouseListener(candidatesMouseAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when I click left on an empty JLabel, nothing happens (System.out.println() is not displayed).

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you’re hitting the (possibly tiny) empty labels?

Comment: Use a GridLayout for you label components. Then even if the text is empty the label will still have a size which will allow you to click on it. For other layout managers the size if probably (0, 0) which means there is nothing to click on. If you need more help then post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I edited my code, as you can see in createView () and placeComponents, the elements of candidatesLabel are in a GridLayout ...

Comment: That is not an [mcve]. Looks to me like you are using a GridBagLayout for the labels, not a GridLayout. All we need is a frame with a panel using a GridLayout and 9 labels and you add the MouseListener to the labels. The whole class would be about 20 lines of code. First get that working. Then fix your real application.

Answer (score 0):

> I already implement an option to add text if I left clicks and it is not empty

It looks like you have that backwards; it will add text if you left click a square that *IS* empty

```
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                ...
                if (source.getText().equals("")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatesLabel.length; ++i) {
                        if (candidatesLabel[i].equals(source)) {
                            candidatesLabel[i].setText("" + (i - 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

> I would now like to be able to detect right clicks on my empty label

Seems to me this works just fine. You don't see anything change as you right click an *empty* label and the text is set to be *empty*

```
              else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < candidatesLabel.length; ++i) {
                    if (candidatesLabel[i].equals(source)) {
                        candidatesLabel[i].setText("");
                    }
                }
```

> when I click left on an empty JLabel, nothing happens (System.out.println() is not displayed).

As shown above left clicking an empty label will set some text in it. 
Left clicking a label with text in it will cause the UI to switch from candidate view to digit view

```
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                ...
                if (source.getText().equals("")) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    digitDisplay();
                    digitLabel.setText(source.getText());
                }
```

This has it's own problems as `digitLabel` has no text and it's size it not set so it is width=0 and height=0 and so it's mousePressed listener can never be executed and you can never get back to the candidate view

Comment: @Nemtecl: Did any of the above comment help?